# Setup Window application along with SQL Server database including structure, data, views, stored procedures, functions, relations

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am trying to setup (deploy) a Windows application along with a SQL Server database. I just followed this site (http://www.rajneeshverma.com/post/2012/08/16/Setup-and-Deployment-of-Windows-Application-with-SQL-Server-Database-using-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx). In this site the database tables, views and stored procedures generating script and keeping in a `.txt` file.

This one working great for table's structure and data separated with `;` but when it comes to views, stored procedures it's not working. I tried it with same separator (`;`) for this text file but it getting error (Error 1001 : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREAT')

Text file example:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Batch_Status_Report] AS ............... EMP ;

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EMP_Report] AS ............... Employer ;
```

If I am not using any separator between the `create view` statements, then I get this error

> Error 1001 : Incorrect syntax near the key word 'CREATE'. 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch )

Text file example:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Batch_Status_Report] AS ............... EMP 
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EMP_Report] AS ............... Employer
```

Could you please any one can help me regarding this separator which one I need to use between views and stored procedures?

Comment: Did you create the script exactly as per the instructions? I would have thought that tables and views would both be in the same script, but you seem to have separate scripts? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Thanks for you reply Mr.Shree, yes all in the same script but it getting error so I was separated tables and views script tried, the tables created successfully but views and Stored procedures cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the statement to create the view as a string to `EXEC`, and separate each `EXEC` statement with a semicolon, like so:

```
EXEC('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Batch_Status_Report] AS ............... EMP');

EXEC('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EMP_Report] AS ............... Employer');
```

This will also work for stored procedures etc.

However, a better approach would be to replace the semicolon separators with `GO`. `GO` can be  used with `sqlcmd` to separate statements into batches. So, you can simply replace `';'` with `' GO'` and then use `sqlcmd` to run the single text file containing all your DDL statements.